# Arabic to latin conversion failure?

Tags: java, icu4j

```
package com.webom.crypt;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils;

import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

public class Test {
        public static String ARABIC_TO_LATIN = "Any-Arabic";
        public static String ARABIC_TO_LATIN_NO_ACCENTS = "Arabic-Latin/BGN; nfd; [:nonspacing mark:] remove; nfc";

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String ARABICString = "صدام حسين التكريتي";

            String unicodeCodes = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(ARABICString);
            System.out.println("Unicode codes:" + unicodeCodes);
            // conversion
            Transliterator ARABICToLatinTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(ARABIC_TO_LATIN);
            String result1 = ARABICToLatinTrans.transliterate(ARABICString);
            System.out.println("ARABIC to Latin:" + result1);
            // conversion       
            Transliterator ARABICToLatinNoAccentsTrans = Transliterator.getInstance(ARABIC_TO_LATIN_NO_ACCENTS);
            String result2 = ARABICToLatinNoAccentsTrans.transliterate(ARABICString);
            System.out.println("ARABIC to Latin (no accents):" + result2);
        }
    }
```

As conversion of **arabic to latin** fails because there is issue regarding to the instances .Could you please find out the correct instance string? As when you  use google translator it will show exact conversion.

Comment: You're going to have to be a whole lot more specific about what's going wrong, before anyone can help you.  Is there a stack trace, or something else to go on?  What output are you expecting, and what output are you getting?

Comment: Arabic text :

صدام حسين التكريتي

Google's transliteration output

: Sadaam Hussein al-tikriti

ICU4J's transliteration outuput

: ṣdạm ḥsyn ạltkryty

Comment: The ICU4J transliteration seems accurate to me.   Arabic is usually written without the short vowels; also, the same letter is used for consonant y and for long i.  Your original text is no exception.  Google Translate has a lot of extra intelligence built in, to guess what the omitted vowels might be.  But there's no way you can expect to get this from a transliteration engine.